# Eclipse "Resource leak" compiler warning doesn't trigger

Tags: java, eclipse, resource-leak

I have a simple Java class as below:

```
public static class NullInputStream extends InputStream {

    public static InputStream wrap(InputStream src) {
        return src == null ? new NullInputStream() : src;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

This code is compiled in `Eclipse 4.5` with Java compliance level `1.8`. The strange thing is happening. In my environment the compiler produces no warnings. Another developer gets the "`Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is never closed`" compiler warning warning on **`new NullInputStream()`**. We determined that the warning must be triggered when "`Resource leak`" is set to "`Warning`" and goes away when it is dropped to "`Ignore`". In my `Eclipse` environment the warning is never triggered regardless of "`Resource leak`" setting.

I spent hours trying to find the reason why the warning doesn't get triggered. I did export/import of compiler preferences from another developer environment, I triple-checked I don't use project specific settings, checked java compiler versions, runtimes, facets etc. - everything is `1.8`

Note. My question is about this specific **compiler warning** not triggered and not the class design. I need the warning to be triggered. Other warnings e.g. "`Dead code`" and "`Potential resource leak`" work and trigger as expected.

Comment: I have found a similar question here, May be It can help you...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463327/is-this-a-memory-leak-or-a-false-positive

Comment: I found one more similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459568/eclipse-inconsistencies-resource-leak-unassigned-closeable-value-is-never

Comment: Questions above are not similar at all. Those developers are lucky to have the compiler warnings triggered as expected. I don't get the warnings. PLEASE READ THE ACTUAL QUESTION :) My problem is I WANT those warnings to be produced but they are not.

Comment: Can you show the calling code in both cases?

Comment: Why? The calling code doesn't matter. I need my Eclipse compiler to produce "Resource leak" warnings on any code similar to the one I have in my question. The compiler seems to ignore the "Resource leak" warning setting in my environment.

Comment: Actually, this warning is not due to anything related to Java code, its a bug in eclipse, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434065
I have tried to understand it, but not sure whether it is resolved or not,
Anyway If its a bug, and then If you are not getting this warning which should not come in my opinion, then its good.. :)

Comment: Does the another developer have the same eclipse version as you?

Comment: @pbajpai21 Genius! The other developer upgraded Eclipse with patches for previous Eclipse version to support 1.8. I just told her to remove the patch and her Eclipse no longer produces the warning! You answered my question.

Comment: @Cherio,,Thanks ..happy coding...